# A more appropriate word for feeling "high"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a more formal or appropriate word to replace the word *high* when writing "feeling high"? 
By feeling "high", I don't mean the person has to be smoking weed or taking crack. So the person is *not* in a trance, feeling dizzy or feeling psychedelic. He is perfectly healthy.

For example, a person dancing in a club, jamming on his guitar, having lots of fun, etc, he could say he is feeling "high".

But the word "high" sounds colloquial. What is a better word to replace feeling "high" in this context for writing?

Comment: This is why we have the phrase *high on life*.

Comment: Is there something wrong with feeling high?

Comment: FWIW, I *have* heard people say they were "high on dancing!"

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[Euphoria](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euphoria), or in this case ***euphoric***.

Comment: straight to the point, simple and easy to understand. Great choice.

Comment: Notably, the definition of "high" includes the word "euphoria" http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high

Comment: But the connotation is that being "high" is being under the influence of a substance. "Euphoria" generally lacks that connotation; while it can be an effect of a drug, disease or other "altered condition", it is just as likely to be used to describe being extremely happy for natural reasons.

Answer (score 36):

You could say that the person is one of the following:

- *feeling alive*
- *in high spirits*
- *in good spirits*
- *lighthearted*
- *upbeat*

Comment: +1 I think you've captured the intent without going into the extreme range that other answers are tending towards.  I think just plain *Happy* fits the bill as well.

Comment: these all boil down to feeling "good", which is not a bad feeling but doesn't capture the ecstasy that "high" does.

Comment: Yep. I was going for words that aren't "over the top." I think euphoria is a little excessive for what was described in the question (but apparently I was incorrect). I think euphoria is more like when you have a child or you get a "Yes" on a marriage proposal.

Answer (score 30):

What about "feeling **elated**"? According to the Oxford Dictionary, if means "very happy and excited because of something good that has happened, or will happen".

or else "**ecstatic**", which in the same dictionary is defined as "very happy, excited and enthusiastic; feeling or showing great enthusiasm". In this meaning, it is said to be a synonym of "**delighted**".

I admit that they all sound a bit stiff and old-fashioned.

Answer (score 14):

The previously-suggested words *[euphoric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euphoric)*, *[elated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elated)*, and *[ecstatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ecstatic)* all are good, but don't overlook *[exhilarated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exhilarated)* ("refreshingly thrilled") and  *[exuberant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exuberant)* ("high-spirited; extremely energetic or enthusiastic").

Answer (score 8):

It's going to be hard to displace a natural and well-established [Metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) like the [***UP/DOWN*** family](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/UPmetaphors.pdf) of metaphor themes.

Being metaphorically ***high***, for whatever reason, and in whatever way, is coherent with the

- ***UP*** is ***HAPPY*** (***DOWN*** is ***SAD***) theme

  - *He’s depressed.*
  - *feeling up/down*
  - *What a downer!*

as well as the

- **UP** is ***BETTER*** (***DOWN*** is ***WORSE***) theme

  - *He fell down on the midterm.*
  - *a rise/fall in performance*
  - *upwardly-mobile*

and the

- **UP** is ***ABSTRACT*** (***DOWN*** is ***CONCRETE***) theme

  - *head in the clouds*
  - *feet on the ground*
  - *Come back to earth.*
  - *new heights of abstraction*

Virtually all the ways we use to talk about mental experiences are metaphors. Nothing new here.

Comment: Your list is pretty long, but you have forgotten the exact answer: "feeling heaven". So -1. Please, read again the xEnOn question.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: That's *your* "exact" answer. Why downvote when someone else doesn't come to the exact same conclusion as you?

Comment: Take a look to the site you have mentioned and you will see yourself.

Comment: Whatever; he clearly didn't read the answer either. Happens all the time.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: What site? I have not mentioned any site.

Answer (score 6):

A phrase (not a single word, unfortunately) to describe this state might be *deliriously happy* or *delirious with joy*.

Comment: Downvoter: why?

Comment: Grammatical rule n. 7: "Exaggeration is a billion times worse than understatement." So -1.

Comment: @Carlo_R. aren't "feeling heaven" and "over the moon" also exaggerations? (I'm not trying to pick a fight or be surly or anything; I just want to understand.)

Comment: You are right. Pardon. I would up-vote your answer but I cannot do that. If you edit your answer, I up-vote.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume this is in regards to proper English usage as opposed to colloquial or slang expressions. If slang a few that come to mind, "On cloud 9" or "On a pink cloud" are a couple.

Answer (score 2):

Exhilarated suggests to me the appropriate sense of a not-intense mood that may extend for about the same amount of time. Most of the other suggestions seem more transient.

Answer (score 1):

Excited. While high as in 'on drugs' might justify words like ecstatic, euphoric, or elated, I am not sure anyone would get into that state playing a guitar.